# Ask for solutions to two improper integrals whose integrands contain the integer powers of the sine function

Tags: integration, analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

Let $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$, and $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a,b>0$. Then
\begin{equation}\label{alpha-n=1-k-odd}\tag{q1}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^{2k-1}t}{t}\sin(\alpha t)\operatorname{d} t
=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^{2k}}\sum_{q=0}^{2k-1}(-1)^q\binom{2k-1}{q}\ln\biggl|\frac{2q-2k+1-\alpha}{2q-2k+1+\alpha}\biggr|
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}\label{a-b-n=1-k-odd}\tag{q2}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^{2k}(a x)}{x}\cos(bx)\operatorname{d} x
=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^{2k+1}}\sum_{q=0}^{2k-1}(-1)^q\binom{2k-1}{q}\ln\biggl|\frac{4a^2(q-k)^2-b^2}{4a^2(q-k+1)^2-b^2}\biggr|.
\end{equation}
Recently, I derived the formulas \eqref{alpha-n=1-k-odd} and \eqref{a-b-n=1-k-odd}. The motivation comes from related results on pp. 464--471 in the monogrpah [1] below and those results in the papers [2] to [6].

Let $m,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\ge2$ and $m-n\ge1$ is odd and let $a,b,\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ such that $a>0$ and $b\ge0$. How to compute or where to find the improper integrals
\begin{equation*}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^{m-1}t}{t^{n}}\sin(\alpha t)\operatorname{d} t
\quad\text{and}\quad
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^{m}(a x)}{x^{n}}\cos(bx)\operatorname{d} x?
\end{equation*}
Due to related results in the monographs [7] and [8], I think that this problem is interesting and significant.

References

1. I. S. Gradshteyn and I. M. Ryzhik, *Table of Integrals, Series, and Products*, Translated from the Russian, Translation edited and with a preface by Daniel Zwillinger and Victor Moll, Eighth edition, Revised from the seventh edition, Elsevier/Academic Press, Amsterdam, 2015; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-12-384933-5.00013-8.
2. Q.-M. Luo, B.-N. Guo, and F. Qi, *Evaluation of a class of improper integrals of the first kind*, Math. Gaz. **87** (2003), no. 510, 534--539; available online at https://doi.org/10.1017/S0025557200173863.
3. Q.-M. Luo and F. Qi, *Evaluation of a class of the first kind improper integrals $\int_0^\infty\bigl(\frac{\sin(\beta x)}{x}\bigr)^n\cos(bx)\operatorname{d} x$*, Octogon Math. Mag. **11** (2003), no. 1, 76--81.
4. Q.-M. Luo and F. Qi, *Evaluation of the improper integrals ${\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^{2m}(a x)}{x^{2n}}\cos(bx)\operatorname{d} x}$ and ${\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^{2m+1}(a x)}{x^{2n+1}}\cos(bx)\operatorname{d} x}$*, Austral. Math. Soc. Gaz. **30** (2003), no. 2, 86--89.
5. F. Qi, Q.-M. Luo, and B.-N. Guo, *Evaluations of the improper integrals $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^{2m}(\alpha x)}{x^{2n}}\operatorname{d} x$ and $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin^{2m+1}(\alpha x)}{x^{2n+1}}\operatorname{d} x$*, J. Korean Soc. Math. Educ. Ser. B Pure Appl. Math. **11** (2004), no. 3, 189--196.
6. A. Sofo, *On the integral $\frac{(\sin x)^{p+q}}{x^q}$*, Internat. J. Math. Ed. Sci. Tech. **29** (1998), no. 6, 914--918.
7. C. I. Valean, *(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series*, with a foreword by Paul J. Nahin, Problem Books in Mathematics, Springer, Cham, 2019; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-030-02462-8.
8. C. I. Valean, *More (almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series---A New Collection of Friendish Problems and Surprising Solutions*, Problem Books in Mathematics, Springer, Cham, 2023; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-031-21262-8.

Comment: Since the integrands are either even or odd (depending on the exponents),, they can be extended to the entire real line. If you then truncate them to $[-R, R]$ and connect the ends by a half-circle of radius $R$ in the complex plane, you get a closed path integral. That path integral is susceptable to the Residue Theorem (the pole on the path contributes half the residue of an interior pole). Since $n \ge 2$, the integral along the half-circle goes to $0$, leaving the integral on the real line to give the full value.

Comment: @PaulSinclair The integrands are odd, your method of the Residue Theorem is invalid seemingly.

Comment: Somehow, I will take years of experience with said method, a well-groomed familiarity of the proofs, and the endorsement of the established mathematicians I learned it from over the offhand opinion of someone who does not even give a reason for their claim.